# SQLITE UPDATE field IF NULL from another table

Tags: c, database, sqlite

I have a [sqlite3](/questions/tagged/sqlite3) DB with a different tables.
What I'm doing is to `UPDATE` the last inserted row of a table with data from another record af the same table, or from another similar table.

I Got it working but I'm wondering if my solution is correct or something is missing and if I could write it in a more compact and speeder way.

Moreover my code is very very unmanageable, because of if in the future the table structure will change I'll must rewrite the query to add or remove fields.

I was wandering if it's possible to write a [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) query that take a whole record from a table and update all `NULL` fields in another record of the same table.

```
sprintf(global_sql, "UPDATE "\
                        "Table1 "\
                    "SET "\
                        "fiedl1 = case when fiedl1 is null then (SELECT fiedl1 FROM Table1 WHERE Table1_id = %d) else fiedl1 end, "\
                        "fiedl2 = case when fiedl2 is null then (SELECT fiedl2 FROM Table1 WHERE Table1_id = %d) else fiedl2 end, "\
                        "fiedl3 = case when fiedl3 is null then (SELECT fiedl3 FROM Table1 WHERE Table1_id = %d) else fiedl3 end "\
                    "WHERE "\
                        "Table1_id = (SELECT max(Table1_id) FROM Table1)", sourceRecord_idx, sourceRecord_idx, sourceRecord_idx);
```

As you can see for each single field I must write its specific `SET` case and moreover the value for each filed is retrieved by a select.

I guess/hope there is a simplier and more maintainable way to do that.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this. And a good thing to because it is not a good idea. There will always be exceptions, and you as the programmer have to be aware of each added field and decide whether an exception applies.

Comment: @Ben I can agree with you, but there is a different way to avoid a single SELECT to retrieve a single field from the source record?

Answer (score 2):

You might consider this slightly more maintainable,
at least it has some "triple-copied-code" less:

```
with shortcut(f1, f2, f3) as
 (SELECT fiedl1, fiedl2, fiedl3 FROM Table1 WHERE Table1_id = %d)
UPDATE Table1 SET 
  fiedl1 = ifnull(fiedl1, (SELECT f1 FROM shortcut)), 
  fiedl2 = ifnull(fiedl2, (SELECT f2 FROM shortcut)), 
  fiedl3 = ifnull(fiedl3, (SELECT f3 FROM shortcut))
WHERE Table1_id = (SELECT max(Table1_id) FROM Table1)
;
```

Details:

- use a CTE for less repetition of conditions and other shortcutting
- use `ifnull` for making the conditional value simpler, shorter

Tested on SQLite 3.9.1, using a fixed value insteadof `%d`.

Comment: Good trick. It is an old project,. I'll get a shot next days.